# Coredata find one array contain values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

i have one core data table,its containing 100 data and one mutable array have some data. iw ant to search the mutable array contain data is present in table or not.mutable array contain 3 params using these params i need to find out an id .that contain i the table 
am using this code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys" ,self.beaconListArray ];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objs = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error) {
    [NSException raise:@"no  find" format:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]];
    NSLog(@"there is noooo  with same id exsist");
}
if (objs.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"there is a with same id exsist. Use update method");
}else {
    NSLog(@"there's no  with same id. Use insert method");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have an array of data. Each data item is a dictionary or a custom object or something and has a uniqueId. You want to insert or update the data into core data.

I am not sure what property you are using for the uniqueId or what type of data you are trying to insert. So this code is just for demonstration.

First get the uniqueIds out of the data.  Something like:

```
NSArray* thingIdArray = [self.beaconListArray valueForKeyPath:@"uuid"];
```

next do a fetch. Your predicate can look something like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"uuid", thingIdArray];
```

next convert the result which is an array of managed objects to dictionary where the key is the uniqueId.

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (CoreDataThing* t in result) {
    NSString* thingId = t.uuid;
    if (thingId) {
        dict[thingId] = t;
    }
}
```

now for each data item you can see if the item already exists

```
for (NSDictionary* a in self.beaconListArray) {
    NSString* thingId = a[@"uuid"];
    CoreDataThing* coreDataThing = dict[thingId];
    if (!coreDataThing) {
         coreDataThing = //create it here and set default values
    }
    [coreDataThing updateWithSomeObject:a]
}
```

Comment: i have one mutable array 
     {
        major = 1;
        minor = 4541;
        uuid = "xxxxxxxx";
    },
        {
        major = 1;
        minor = 6000;
        uuid = "xxxxxxx";
    },
using this data i want to search in coredata  datatable and find out corresponding id.using that id i need to display something in my view.
How to get these